# Playing .Flac or .Alac files using react native, is it even possible on iphone?

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native, mobile

I'm creating a react native app for audio playback and would prefer using .flac or .alac files.
The app is working well using .wav files but importing .flac files causes a crash.

So I'm getting this error:

iOS Bundling failed 3555ms
Unable to resolve module ../../assets/Pain-Inflammation.flac from C:\Users\samir\Source\OctaCoil\apps\context\AudioProvider.js:

None of these files exist: assets\Pain-Inflammation.flac(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
assets\Pain-Inflammation.flac\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
16 |       id: 1,
17 |       title: 'Energize',

> 18 |       url: require('../../assets/Pain-Inflammation.flac'),
> |                     ^
> 19 |       duration: 30.00,
> 20 |       type: 'heart'

And this is part of my code which I believe is relevant.

```
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { storeAudioForNextOpening } from '../misc/helper';
import { playNext } from '../misc/audioController';

export const AudioContext = createContext();

export class AudioProvider extends Component {
  audioItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Energize',
      url: require('../../assets/Pain-Inflammation.flac'),
      duration: 30.00,
      type: 'heart'
    },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to `require` the Flac file, which won't work because the interpreter is attempting to read that as a ts/js source file (which it's not). Drop the `require` and provide the correct path to the asset file and it will at least stop throwing that error:

```js
// ...
export class AudioProvider extends Component {
  audioItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Energize',
      url: '../../assets/Pain-Inflammation.flac',
      duration: 30.00,
      type: 'heart'
    },
// ...
```

That said, Flac playback *should* work on iOS 11+, but that depends on the implementation that the `expo-av` provides. If it's using `AudioToolbox` and/or `AVFoundation` for iOS, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bensnider. Removing 'required' did stop throwing the error but the file is still not being played. You mentioned *should* work? looking at the expo documentation .flac (or alac) is supported. Running out of ideas here, any input?

Comment: @SamirHassen If you transcode to a different format, does it play? If so that's a codec issue with flac, if not then I'd make sure the path to the file is correct and it's being appropriately bundled into the app.